# jQuery send message from form

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to send some message to other php file? I should to see "Loading" or result from my imput. I try to find some answer even this code is from this place, but still dosn't work.
I have:

```
<form>
something<input name="sthis" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $('submit').click(function(){
    $('#container').append('loading');
      var sthis = $('#sthis').val();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'form1.php' , 
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'sthis: ' + sthis,
         success: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>' +     result + '</p>')      
         }
      });   
      return false;     
   });
});
});

</script>
```

Form1.php

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['sthis'];
echo $str;
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're using the `data` argument correctly, it looks wrong. Should be more like `data: 'sthis=' + sthis,`

Comment: Use the dev tools in your browser or something like Firebug so that you can see the request / response that occurs when using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1">
<input name="sthis" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#container').append('loading');
      var data = $('#form1').serialize();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'form1.php' , 
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
         success: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>' +     result + '</p>')      
         }
      });   
      return false;     
   });

</script>
```

This will send all data from your form to php file

Comment: Why i can see this ? success: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>' +     result + '</p>')      
         }

Comment: there isn't actually any #container on site, so it may throw some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think should be like

```
 data: {"sthis": sthis},
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are some things you have to change in your script:

```
$(function(){
  $(':submit').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#container').append('loading');
      var sthis = $('#sthis').val();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'form1.php' , 
         type: 'POST',
        data: {'sthis': sthis},
         success: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>' +     result + '</p>');      
         }
      });   
      return false;     
   });
});
```

First there is an extra }); at the end you can remove.

Your input field must have an id with the name sthis, not just a name, so you can access it with $("#sthis"), like this:

```
<input name="sthis" type="text" id="sthis" />
```

3rd, change your the data line so it look like this:

```
data: {'sthis': sthis},
```

Also, to capture the event of the button you have to use $(':submit'), watch for the :

Comment: It is working here http://jsbin.com/ovifet/1. It is the same code except that it does not have a form1.php file

Comment: <div id = "container">
  <form>
something<input name="sthis" id="sthis" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
  </div> i add div container and i can see only loading

Comment: Are you sure your page is returning something? Try change the line $('#container').append('<p>'+ result + '</p>'); to $('#container').append('<p> Test:' + result + '</p>'); so if the ajax call is ok, you will see the word Test

Comment: Also, if the ajax call is failling in can try adding this code: error: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>Error</p>');      
         } Just to know if the ajax call is working